# Longest common prefix

Tags: javascript, algorithm, strings, programming-challenge

I have made a function for finding the longest common prefix for the challenge on the [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-common-prefix/description/) site. This is the code:

```
var longestCommonPrefix = function(strs) {
    let longestPrefix = '';
    if (strs.length > 0) {
      longestPrefix = strs[0];
      for (let i = 1; i < strs.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < longestPrefix.length; j++) {
          if (strs[i][j] != longestPrefix[j]) {
            longestPrefix = longestPrefix.slice(0, j);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return longestPrefix;
};
```

I am sure there is a way to make this code better, but not sure how to do that. Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4):

I would find the alphabetically smallest and largest string and just run your algorithm on these two. That would avoid the embedded loop.

```
var longestCommonPrefix = function(strs) {
    if (!strs)
        return '';

    let smallest = strs.reduce( (min, str) => min < str ? min : str, strs[0] );
    let largest  = strs.reduce( (min, str) => min > str ? min : str, strs[0] );

    for (let i=0; i<smallest.length; i++) {
        if (smallest[i] != largest[i])
            return smallest.substr(0,i);
    }

    return '';
};
```

In answer to `konijn` it would be minimally faster to get the smallest/largest by doing:

```
let smallest = strs[0];
let largest  = strs[0];
for (let i=1; i<strs.length; i++) {
  let s= strs[i];
  if (s > largest)  largest = s;
  if (s < smallest) smallest = s;
}
```

Comment: Would a `sort` with a `pop` and an `unshift` not be faster?

Comment: fwiw, I wouldn't use `shift` since it requires moving all the elements in the array, `[0]` would be quicker. Even `pop` requires modifying the array, but to answer your comment most sorts are quite expensive O(n.log n) or O(n^2) and require a lot of moving and copying. The two calculations could be combined in a loop if performance was really critical (see my addition)

Comment: How you you return an answer by inspecting only the shortest and longest?  Consider {'ab', 'acd', 'abcd'} -> 'a'

Comment: Because if the smallest and largest string share a common prefix every other string would share it too. For  example 'abaaa' and 'adeee' share the prefix 'a' everything inbetween ('abbbb', 'ac', 'ada', 'adaa') will all share the same prefix.

Comment: For input with n strings, this algorithm compare (2n-1) times while OP's solution compare (n-1) times. Although they all compare O(n) times. This solution may be notable slower than OP's answer.

Answer (score 2):

From a short review;

- You should sort the strings by length ascending if you start by assigning `longestPrefix = strs[0];` the prefix cannot be longer than the shortest string.
- I would assign `longestPrefix[j]` to a variable, avoiding an array access in a nested loop
- I would `return` the found value instead of calling `break`

  - Break only exits one iteration in the loop anyway
  - It seems okay that if no string list is provided, that `undefined` is returned
- Personal preference, I prefer `list` over `strs`
- `function(strs)` creates an anonymous function, which is terrible in stack traces, just use the good old `function longestCommonPrefix(strs) {`
  *

Comment: Firefox 53 (released on April 2017), Chrome 51 (released in 2016) may infer function name from assignment and show it in stack traces as required by ES2015. So using anonymous function is not a problem if you are debugging on these platform any more (at least when this question post).